# Django: AttributeError: type object 'GroupModel' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django

I am new in Django, in my code when I requested from postman I got this error, may someone help me what's wrong in my code?

model:

```
from django.db import models

class GroupModel(object):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'group'
    def __str__(self):
        return self
```

---

serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import GroupModel

class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    print('hello4')
    class Meta:
        model = GroupModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from .serializer import GroupSerializer
from .models import GroupModel
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework import status
@api_view(['POST'])
def InsetGroup(request):
     data = GroupSerializer(data = request.data)

     if request.method == 'POST':
         if data.is_valid():
             data.save()
             return JsonResponse('saved was saccessfull', safe = False)
         return JsonResponse(data.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, safe = False)
```

Comment: Your `GroupModel` did not inherit from `Model`.

Answer (score 3):

Models in Django need to be a *subclass* of the [**`Model`** class [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model):

```
from django.db import models

class GroupModel(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'group'
```

Your `__str__` should also return a `str`ing, so for example `self.title`, *not* `self`, since that is a `GroupModel` object, not a `str`ing.

Answer (score 1):

Tip: In order to improve your code you don't need to check if "is_valid()" is true or not. You could use "is_valid(raise_exception=True)" to raise a 400 error automatically if there is something wrong.